# Modern method to run Django scripts as alternate user in Apache deployment

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I have seen a number of similar questions, however none seem to have current solutions.

I have a Django deployment running on Apache and mod_wsgi, as outlined in the Django guides [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), hosted on an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server. By default, Apache, and hence any python script run by it, is run as the `www-data` user. I have some scripts on my website that require privileged access to run, and for security reasons I would like to avoid granting the necessary privileges to www-data to run these scripts directly. Ideally I'd like a solution I can implement directly in the relevant `views.py` file to run the privileged script as a user with the permissions to do so only after inputs have been sanitized. What are my options to achieve this?

As an example of a script requiring privileged access: my company uses this web portal for (among other things) setting up remote servers at client sites. That setup requires ssh access, which is restricted to certain users, and should not be granted to the www-data user.

I have considered recreating the privileged scripts as daemon processes, however they do not need to be run frequently so I don't feel it's worth the work, and would prefer to keep things as integrated with base Django as possible. The scripts also do not run on a predefined schedule where a crontab would do the trick.

What I'm envisioning is a daemon process running as a privileged user, listening for specific inputs from the www-data user, to then run the appropriate script and return data. It is this communication I am not sure how to implement (or if there is a better method already-built, as I imagine this must be a common problem in secure environments).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go the daemon route. This consisted of two distinct pieces:

1. A background process running as a privileged user listening on a local port with `socket` for pre-defined inputs to spawn pre-defined processes - this is the daemon
2. An communication function built into a shared module that sends pre-formatted commands to the daemon and handles communication of output (also via `socket`)

Once that was built all I had to do to implement it was replace direct calls to the privileged scripts with calls to the shared communication function.

A couple things to keep in mind if someone else implements a similar system:

- Note that the daemon is listening on a network port. Assuming you only want local users to be able to call the daemon, ensure whatever port you chose is closed either with a software firewall (e.g. `UFW`) or ideally a hardware one
- In my implementation the only thing keeping unprivileged users from calling the daemon is understanding how to format the commands. If someone knew this (e.g. if they had the source code of the daemon) they could easily send commands to it from any local account. For my implementation this was not a concern, as everyone with access to the server would be authorized to do that anyway, and if a bad actor gained server access and read access to the source code there would be much bigger problems at hand, but it is worth keeping in mind as your needs may vary.